# change picturebox size , spacing between buttons when user changes window size

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, autosize, docking

i am developing a win form application using c# ,in form 1 there is a datagridview, a panel which holds some text boxes , another panels which holds some labels

how to get this : size of datagridview , spacing between panels,must be changed automatically when the user changes window size

for example as we see in web browser, i think there is a term something like "responsive " ??

Comment: Please don't roll back edits that improved the post.

Comment: i asked a question which i need , how can some one fully alter my question

Comment: Firstly they didn't "fully alter" your question. They fixed the grammar and spelling. Secondly [check the license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) that you sign up for when posting to Stack Exchange.

Comment: thanks for support but i rolled back because beginners like me are likely to search with almost same keywords as i asked in question...i hope seniors don't mind

Comment: Can you at least fix the spelling and grammar.

Comment: It is recommended not to roll back the edits as they help to simplify the post and facilitate a simple approach to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use Anchor of your controls.Using anchor you can anchor it top ,bottom left right 
take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx)

Or you can also use [Table Layout Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx)